# Выборка определенных пунктов меню по TV параметру, Modx

Tags: cms, modx

Есть на сайте страница сотрудника (шаблон), на этой странице выводится инфо о этом самом сотруднике и связанные проекты. Так вот вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы выборка проектов осуществлялась по имени автора, которое я прописываю в тв поле с проектом? Я знаю, что в pdoResources есть такой параметр как &tvFilters, но в pdoMenu не могу догадаться как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот вывод сниппета:

```
[[pdoMenu?
                        &parents         = `3`
                        &limit           = `0`
                        &level           = `0`
                        &showUnpublished = `0`
                        &resources       = `-12`
                        &sortby          = `RAND()`
                        &tplOuter        = `@INLINE <div class="blog">[[+wrapper]]</div>`
                        &tpl             = `@INLINE [[$project_item]]`
                        &includeTVs      = `author,project_img,shorttext,filter,project_sort,date`
                    ]]
```

Чанк project_item:

```
<div class="width-small">
<div class="blog-post">
    <a href="[[+link]]"><img src="[[+project_img]]" alt="" /></a>
    <h3 class="t-left"><a href="#">[[+pagetitle]]</a></h3>
    <ul class="t-left lato f-small">
        <li class="no-margin">Автор: <a href="#">[[+author]]</a></li>
        <li>Дата: [[+date]]</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="t-left">
        [[+shorttext]]
    </p>
    <a href="[[+link]]" class="button">Подробнее</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать параметр `where` (Массив дополнительных параметров выборки, закодированный в JSON.)

```
&where=`{"author":"[[*name_author]]"}`
```

Я не знаю, как вы передаете имя автора.

Ссылка на синтаксис: http://mudrenizm.ru/index.php?id=120

Comment: А как пользоваться этим массивом не подскажете? Здесь возможно использовать название TV поля и его значение?

Comment: В чанке с шаблоном пункта меню есть tv поле [[+author]].
Выше в вопросе оно есть кстати

Comment: Добавил ссылку на синтаксис, а насчет имени автора: в шаблоне проекта у вас есть дополнительное tv поле [[+author]] - это автор проекта, а вот само имя (т.е. значение) по которому надо отобрать проекты должно быть у вас где-то

Comment: Да, есть значение, спасибо огромное за ссылку и помощь! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Глупо спрашивать, но все же спрошу, а этот синтаксис и для pdoMenu подходит?

Comment: это и для него тоже, т.е. у pdoresources и pdomenu синтаксис оператора where одинаковый, просто у pfomenu нет tvFilters

Comment: Если я записываю вот так, то не работает:
&where    =   `{"+author":"+pagetitle"}`

Comment: &where = ` `{"author":"[[+pagetitle]]"}` `

Comment: Круто! Благодарю, волшебство прямо) Только там через * так как сниппет непосредственно в шаблоне прописан, спасибо еще раз, низкий поклон!